# Flutter Bloc - update repository data source URL

Tags: flutter, architecture, repository, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have 2 data sources, one of them have static URL to server, but second data source’s URL will depend on response from first server or user can pass his own server URL.
Dynamic url for some custom server.
Api (api interfaces) will be the same, only URL will be dynamic

How to handle this approach using bloc architecture from docs

As I see. Use repository setters for this thing. Like _repo.secondDataSourceUrl = “http…”

And inside repository, unless second URL will be provided, repo will return error when you try to make requests from second data source "You did not set second URL"

Answer (score 0):

As I found  Setters are fine. But other solution, if you do not want to use them, just use second dynamic URL as a parameter along side with other eg tokens, emails etc